# Why can't I iterate over class prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have the following non logging code:

```js
class test {a(){}}

for(const a in test.prototype)
    console.log(a)
```

Any ideas why - if I debug it I can see the methods inside test.prototype

I'm using nodejs.

Comment: Why use a `for ... in` loop instead of `test.prototype.a`?

Answer (score 3):

The methods created on the prototype object via a `class` declaration are made non-enumerable implicitly. You can do that yourself for any object:

```
function Constructor() { }

Object.defineProperty(Constructor.prototype, "a", {
  value: function() { },
  enumerable: false
});
```

(The `enumerable` and `writable` flags are `false` by default so you don't even have to explicitly include it.)

Comment: So how can I enumerate them ?

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions well you could explicitly override the `enumerable` property I guess. Why do you *want* to enumerate them? They're made non-enumerable because that avoids much of what made `for ... in` a bad idea for so many years.