# Why can't I iterate over the properties of a class before creating an instance?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

Can someone explain to me why I can't iterate over the properties (edit: falsely wrote prototypes first) of a class without creating an instance of it? A stupid little example would be:

```js
export class Animal {
  name: string;
  colour: string;

  constructor(init: string[]) {
    this.name = init[0];
    this.color = init[1]
  }
}
```

Now, somewhere else in the program (long before the first book is "created"), I would like to do this:

```js
for (const key in  Object.keys(Animal) {
  // here I would expect to iterate over the keys 'name' and 'colour' so I can do something like:
  console.log(Animal[key]);
}
```

I'm aware, that it's not possible (previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53413723/why-cant-i-iterate-over-class-prototype) and also according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)). But I don't understand the provided explanations. Could you explain to me why this is the case?

And, as a follow-up, how would I handle such a situation? Should I create an external interface/type that I loop over? I would generally like to have a single place that "holds" my animal properties.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Well `name` and `colour` are not even part of the prototype, there dynamically created.  So won't exist until created.   The typescript definition of `name:string` is only compile time info that Typescript understands, but Javascript does not.

Comment: I have a dropdown menu and I would like to select which properties should later be selected/displayed when the "animal" is created. But, based on your answer, it seems like I'm really trying something stupid here :')

Comment: `I'm really trying something stupid here :')`  Not really, you just need to approach this slightly differently.   One idea is to create a constant array of props, you can then generate a Type for this to make sure Animal implements them.  You will then have compile & runtime info you could use.

Comment: That's good input, thank you! I'll stop trying to do stuff directly on the class and try to  create a common array and interface/type that I can implement in both use-cases.

Answer (score 1):

Because the properties of Animal are non-enumerable as can be seen in this example:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Animal)

{
  "length": {
    "value": 1,
    "writable": false,
    "enumerable": false,
    "configurable": true
  },
  "name": {
    "value": "Animal",
    "writable": false,
    "enumerable": false,
    "configurable": true
  },
  "prototype": {
    "value": {},
    "writable": false,
    "enumerable": false,
    "configurable": false
  }
}
```

If you set the properties in the class to static they become enumerable.
Alternatively you can iterate them this way:

```
for (const key in  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Animal)) {
  console.log(Animal[key]);
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the input! Wouldn't setting it to static mean that f.e. every animal has the same name?

Comment: Yes, they would share one name, but you could also do Object.defineProperty(Animal.prototype,'name',{
    "value": "Animal",
    "writable": false,
    "enumerable": true,
    "configurable": true
  }), and thereby overwrite the default settings of the property.